# Как сделать плавную смену позиции виджета в GtkBox

Tags: c, gtk+, glade

Нужно сделать плавную смену позиции виджета в gtkbox,функцией `gtk_box_reorder_child()` меняю позицию виджета `gtkrevealer` под номером 4, но нужно это сделать плавно, что мне нужно использовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю стоит начать с - https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRevealer.html
А вот пишут про GtkBox и GtkRevealer - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1020 Ну и обратить внимание что GtkRevealer работает с версии - The GtkRevealer widget was added in GTK+ 3.10.

Comment: @karaname, упс , придется перезадать вопрос